# histograms in R

Tags: r, excel, plot, histogram

I have a file like this

```
>distance       A        B
>-100000        0        0
-99975        8.99341232547159e-07        8.99341232547159e-07
-99950        1.79868246509432e-06        1.79868246509432e-06
........
.......
99950        2.69802369764148e-06        0
99975        0        8.99341232547159e-07
100000        0        4.4967061627358e-06
```

I want to create a histogram(in R or excel) with the distance as x-coordinates 
and with values A and B

> for example something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=homer%20histogram&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=U3rDUZOrCIn7igKev4DABQ&biw=1920&bih=979&sei=VXrDUceGBOHeiALA-4C4Dg#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=LvvAZUfcdnLeMM%3a;Q728nGjxBnWQpM;http%253A%252F%252Fbiowhat.ucsd.edu%252Fhomer%252Fchipseq%252FhistARtags.png;http%253A%252F%252Fbiowhat.ucsd.edu%252Fhomer%252Fchipseq%252Fhistogram.html;532;411)

any help would be great!

**EDIT** (add a reproducible data)

```
dat <- data.frame(distance <- seq(-100000 ,100000 ,100000-99975 ),
                  A=rnorm(length(distance)),
                  B=rnorm(length(distance)))
```

Comment: I would suggest to post a reproducible example. and btw if `A` and `B` already represent the value to plot then your just want a simple line chart. have a look to `?plot`

Comment: i can produce a line chart as you said,but i am looking in for histogram that i showed to you @Michele

Comment: I know but your data seems already a distribution so, you don't a histogram but a line chart... the problem is. post a reproducible `data.frame`. no one can help this way.

Comment: @abh I edit you post to add a reproducible data. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code:

```
dat <- data.frame(distance <- seq(-1500 ,1500 ,25),
                  A=rnorm(length(distance),mean=0,sd=0.1),
                  B=rnorm(length(distance),mean=0,sd=0.09))

plot(dat[,c(1,2)],type="l",
     col="blue",
     main="My Title",
     xlab="My X Label",
     ylab="My Y Label",
     axes=F)
lines(dat[,c(1,3)],type="l",col="red")

axis(1, pos=0,las=1)
axis(2, pos=0,las=1)

legend("topright", pch = c("-","-"), 
       col = c("blue", "red"), 
       legend = c("A", "B"))
```